# MDX - multiple filters on different dimension with OR condition

Tags: mdx

I have a problem with MDX querying.

I have one measure `WEIGHT` and two dimensions `DESTINATION` and `SOURCE` with the same attributes: `NAME` and `TYPE`.

I want to return:

```
SUM of WEIGHT 
where 
   DESTINATION.TYPE="A" 
   **OR** 
   SOURCE.TYPE="B" 
   **AND** 
      (DESTINATION.TYPE **<>** SOURCE.TYPE)
```

If try this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
   [Measures].[Weight] 
} 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
   ([Source].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Destination].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} 
ON ROWS 
FROM 
( SELECT ( { [Source].[Type].&[A] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Destination].[Type].&[B] } )
     ON COLUMNS FROM [CUBE])) WHERE ( [Destination].[Type].&[B], [Source].[Type].&[A] )
```

But it doesn't work.

In SQL it look like

```
Select source.name, destination.name, sum(weight) from cube
where
(source.type = "A" or destination.type = "b")
and 
(source.type <> destination.type)
group by source.name, destination.name, source.type, destination.type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your From section is a bit messy. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Weight] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { [Source].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Destination].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS 
FROM [CUBE]
WHERE ( {[Destination].[Type].&[B]} * {[Source].[Type].[All]} + {[Destination].[Type].[All]} * {[Source].[Type].&[A]} )
```

Comment: But it still return me only sum of weight where [Destination].[Type].&[B] **AND** [Source].[Type].&[A]. I want use condition where [Destination].[Type].&[B] **OR** [Source].[Type].&[A]

Comment: I Add yet: WHERE ( {[Destination].[Type].&[B]} * {EXCEPT([Source].[Type].[All].Children, [Source].[Type].&[A]} + {EXCEPT([Destination].[Type].[All].Children, [Destination].[Type].&[B]} * {[Source].[Type].&[A]} ) and work **GREAT** Thanks

Comment: Good to know. Could you please mark it answered in order to let other people know the issue is resolved.

Comment: @DanyloKorostil still seems a little messy. Is this not tidier? `WHERE  { ([Destination].[Type].&[B], [Source].[Type].[All]), ([Destination].[Type].[All],  [Source].[Type].&[A]) }`  ... a set of two tuples.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add [Destination].[Type].AllMembers, [Source].[Type].AllMembers to ROWS? When I try to add it I got an error: The Type hierarchy already appears in the Axis1 axis. I find that the solution is add subquery but how to do it with **OR** condition?

Comment: Simply put your where clause to the axis: Non Empty { ([Destination].[Type].&[B], [Source].[Type].[All]), ([Destination].[Type].[All], [Source].[Type].&[A]) } on rows

Comment: And I think my last question. How to do this if in filtering (Non Empty { ....} I have few different hierarchy? Now I have an error:  Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function. In my query: First condition: , [Transaction].[Status].&[A], [Transaction].[Direction].&[Out],[Source].[Type].&[H] **OR**  [Transaction].[Status].&[A], [Transaction].[Direction].&[In], [SourceSite].[Type].&[D] . I try use WITH SET but i had the same error.

Comment: What do you suggest your output should look like? Try: Non Empty {[Destination].[Type].&[B],[Destination].[Type].[All]} * {[Source].[Type].[All],[Source].[Type].&[A]} on rows

Comment: Also you may try to unite them: Non Empty {{[Destination].[Type].&[B]} * {[Source].[Type].[All]} + {[Destination].[Type].[All]} * {[Source].[Type].&[A]}} on rows.

Comment: No. Thats is not good. What i mean is that I have a query: 
'WHERE
Waste = "R"
And (
Direction is "IN" **and Source is a "D"** and Destination = "T"
Or
Direction is "IN" **and Site is a "H"** and Destination = "T"'

The different is in secound clouse. There is a different hierarchy.